# Keras unrealistic results

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I try to do a creditcard-fraud prediction with keras.
For that, I have a creditcard.csv file, with over 280 000 different cases which are all labeled as fraud or valid.

My problem is, that my code actually does compile, but in the first epoche, my accuracy is already 0.9979 and from the second epoche on acc: 0.9982.

That doesn't seem to be very realistic to me, but I don't know my mistake.

Here is the shortened version of my code:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras import models
from keras import layers

combinedData = pd.read_csv('creditcard.csv')
trainData = combinedData[:227845]
testData = combinedData[227845:]

trainDataFactors = trainData.copy()
del trainDataFactors['Class']
trainDataLabels = pd.DataFrame(trainData, columns=['Class'])

testDataFactors = testData.copy()
del testDataFactors['Class']
testDataLabels = pd.DataFrame(testData, columns=['Class'])

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(30, activation="relu", input_shape = (30, )))
model.add(layers.Dense(60, activation ="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(30, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(
              optimizer = "rmsprop",
              loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics = ["accuracy"]
             )

history = model.fit(
                    trainDataFactors, trainDataLabels,
                    epochs = 20,
                    batch_size = 512,
                    validation_data=(testDataFactors, testDataLabels)
                    )
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your test data balanced?

Because if not, e.g. it's collection of real data, I'd guess that a degenerate model replying "valid" to any input could easily get > 99 % acc. Try reporting also F1 score, that's the default choice for (unbalaced) detection tasks.

Comment: Ah didn't know that this would be an issue. There are only around 500 frauds under 280000 valid transactions. Would it make sense just to delete a bunch of valid transactions for training?

Comment: Deleting sounds as wasting. I'd suggest to have a balanced training data for every epoch, but always pick a different/random set of valid transactions. You might also want to adjust the bias in the output layer afterwards.